# Accessing typed express response

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I'm trying to extend the `express` `Response` type like this:

```
class Registration {
  public static register(express: Application) {
    express.response.someFunction = function () {
      ...
    };
  }
}
```

But I get this Typescript error:

`Property 'response' does not exist on type 'Application'.`

Which type do I have to use instead of `Application`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the `Response` interface provided by `express` using augmentation. `Application` does not have a `response` property, you must add a middleware function to add the function to each request:

```
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Response {
            someFunction(): string
        }
    }
}

class Registration {
    public static register(express: Application) {
        express.use((req, res, next) => {
            res.someFunction = function () {
                return "foo"
            };
        });
    };

}
Registration.register(app);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.someFunction();
    res.send({
        test: res.someFunction()
    })
})
```

Comment: This will work but in opposite to the original question this will cause the `res.someFunction` declaration to be called in every request, correct?

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler yes the assignment will happen on each request. The declaration itself should not be an issue if you don't close over any locals. If you do, cache the closure in some class field so as not to create a closure instance each time ..